# How can I reload my changes on Spring Boot without having to restart my server?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, netbeans

I use spring boot 2.0.0 with netbeans 8.2 and gradle.

I use

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
```

How to avoid to restart every time server when i do a change in the code ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to reload the changes still?

If so you would need to look at another technology like `JRebel` which can reload without a restart.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart

However, for just disabling the restart , 
`spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false` can be set within a properties file. There is a gotcha to disable it completely which requires a system property set, documented here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable

Comment: ya reload change... with the spring boot linkyou provide, don't need jrebel to do that, that should be automatic

Comment: Please read the section `Reload vs. Restart`.

Devtools works via restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is JRebel, but it's not free.

Using dev-tools will make your restart faster and automatic, but will not eliminate it. In my Spring Boot/AngularJS projects I use dev-tools + LiveReload (to reload HTML/JavaScript files dynamically) and I'm quite satisfied.